# How to unlist a list of multiple tibbles into different data frames and rename them?

Tags: r, list, rename

I need to unlist a list of multiple tibbles into different data frames. In addition I want to add "_new" to the name of each unlisted data frame. I tried the following but renaming doesn't go as I wish (i.e., two separate data frames called (a_new and b_new).
Besides, I prefer to avoid using a loop but not sure how to use apply function for that. Could you please help me with that?

```
old_list <- list( a = tibble(AAA = rep("HEN", 16), 
                             BBB = rep(1, 16), 
                             CCC = rep(14, 16)),
                  b = tibble(GGG = rep("DOG", 16), 
                             DDD = rep(5, 16), 
                             FFF = rep(9, 16)))

new <- list()
for (name in names(old_list)){
  rename_tables <- paste0(name,"_new")
  new[[rename_tables]] <- list2env(old_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to "unlist" the data.frames and bring them to the global environment?

Comment: I want to have two data frames called "a_new" and "b_new" in the global environment.

Comment: @Rara You don't need loop for that. Try `names(old_list) <- paste0(names(old_list), "_new"); list2env(old_list, .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: @benson23 Thank you! very simple and neat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach:

```
new_list <- setNames(old_list, paste0(names(old_list), '_new'))
```

to spawn the `df`s into your workplace if need be ;-)

```
new_list |> list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

or short:

```
setNames(old_list, paste0(names(old_list), '_new')) |>
    list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```